# Use event handlers from imported C++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I'm using a 3rd party C library that offers methods and some event handlers. I want to subscribe to one or more events, but I have no clue on how to do that in combination with importing the C library in C#.

The methods aren't a problem. For example I use this

```
[C++]
    API ResultType DoSometing(DeviceHandle devHndl);

[C#]
    [DllImport("Some.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern ErrorType DoSomething(IntPtr devHndl);
```

For the events I have the following definition:

```
[C++]
typedef ResultType (CALLING_CONVENTION *FPtr_GetStatus)(DeviceHandle);
typedef void (CALLING_CONVENTION *FPtr_DeviceEventHandler)(DeviceHandle devHndl, DeviceEvent event, void *context);
API FPtr_DeviceEventHandler RegisterSomeEventHandler(FPtr_DeviceEventHandler handler, void *context);
```

Any idea on how the handle this in the C# code?

Answer (score 1):

Those *event handlers* are actually callback functions. So you would have to use delegates on the C# side.

Something along these lines..

```
delegate ResultType GetStatusDelegate(IntPtr deviceHandle);
delegate void DeviceEventDelegate(IntPtr deviceHandle, DeviceEvent e, IntPtr context);

[DllImport("Some.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void RegisterSomeEventHandler(DeviceEventDelegate handler, IntPtr context);
```

What's missing from the example above are the declarations for the `ResultType` and `DeviceEvent` which weren't available in the question. Those would also have to be declared.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But I have no idea how to combine those with dll import. I am using delegates in my project, so that's not the issue.

Comment: @pattiman - have you looked at the sample code I just posted?

Comment: Gotta love these drive-by down votes. This is supposed to be a community.. how about some indication as to what's wrong with the answer so I can correct (or remove it if necessary)

Comment: Hi Mike. At the time I wrote my comment, the code was not there yet. I will try it now. (I'm not responsible for the -1, btw)

Comment: @pattiman - I figured it wasn't you.. There's actually two -1 votes. Anyway, one thing to keep in mind with these callback is that you need to make sure the functions you wrap in the delegate don't get garbage collected (ie. use static functions, or store references to the delegates in a long lived object). Let me know how it goes!

Comment: @pattiman - out of curiosity.. Were you able to get it working?

Comment: Miky, I wasn't until know. On monday I will continue to work on this. I'll keep you informed. Btw, even my question is now -1 ;-)

Comment: Yeah.. I saw that and it was strange. Your question was definitely a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`delegate`.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/delegate)

[C# Delegates: Step by Step](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/109000/C-Delegates-Step-by-Step)

[Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx